# Does there exist prime number of the form $n^n+s(n)^{s(n)}$ after the trivial one $1^1+1^1$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let n be a positive integer and let s(n) be the digit's sum of n. Is there a prime number of the form $n^n+s(n)^{s(n)}$ ? after the trivial one $1^1+1^1$ ?, I've checked n up to $2500$ without finding a prime anymore (!). I found that numbers of such form often divisible by small primes below $100$, and occasionally they have large least prime factor, but after that they become divisible by small primes again (very often!). Is there a prime number of such form after the trivial one 2 ?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm sure you meant to put this on *MATH.stackexchange.com*...

Comment: If s(n)=n+1, dp you mean $n^n+(n+1)^{n+1}$?

Comment: @martycohen For what positive integer $n$ can the digit sum of $n$ exceed $n$?

Comment: This problem is very weird. I cannot find by computation a single prime in any odd-numbered base. Base 10 I cannot find and 16 is quite stubborn, too.

Comment: I found no prime for $1<n\le 5700$

Comment: I don't see why there should be no other solutions. Are there infinitely many primes of the form $n^n+m^m$? It wouldn't be surprising. They're probably just way too large to find.

Comment: Looking at $n^{s(n)}+s(n)^n$ might be fun.  You get at least one more prime.  (@barto, primes of the form $n^m+m^n$ seem to be plentiful, early on at least.)

Comment: @BarryCipra In this case, the numbers $n$ leading to a prime upto $n=1000$ are $0,1,10,100$

Answer (score 0):

I'm just stating a few trivial facts:

If $n$ is divisible by $3$ then clearly the number is not prime as it's divisible by 3 and greater than $3$.

If $n$ and $s_n$ are both even then also it's not prime.

For a general proof, I believe a mathematical proof is way very difficult and wouldn't be elementary.

Comment: In place of your second point, you might say that if $n$ and $s_n$ have the same parity, then it's not prime (except for $n=1$).